# Find count of points that are closer then 1 pixel away

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I have a few hexagons drawn in SkiaSharp. All the corners are stored in a `List<HexagonRegistryList>`.
Now I want to know how many shared edges the a hexagon has with the rest of the hexagons, so I created this code:

```
public class HexagonRegistryList
{
    public int HexagonNum { get; set; }
    public float x1 { get; set; }
    public float y1 { get; set; }
    public float x2 { get; set; }
    public float y2 { get; set; }
    public float x3 { get; set; }
    public float y3 { get; set; }
    public float x4 { get; set; }
    public float y4 { get; set; }
    public float x5 { get; set; }
    public float y5 { get; set; }
    public float x6 { get; set; }
    public float y6 { get; set; }
    public int ShapeNum { get; set; }

    public HexagonRegistryList()
    {
        this.AdjacentShapeNumbers = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> AdjacentShapeNumbers { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<(float x, float y)> GetPoints()
    {
        yield return (x1, y1);
        yield return (x2, y2);
        yield return (x3, y3);
        yield return (x4, y4);
        yield return (x5, y5);
        yield return (x6, y6);
    }

    public bool IsAdjacentTo(HexagonRegistryList other)
    {
        var isAdjacentTo = GetPoints().Intersect(other.GetPoints()).Count() >= 2;
        if (isAdjacentTo)
        {
            if (other.ShapeNum != 0)
            {
                AdjacentShapeNumbers.Add(other.ShapeNum);
            }
        }
        return isAdjacentTo;
    }
}
```

Now this code works, except for points that are not exactly the same but have a difference of 0.001 pixel. So I want to change this to a comparison function which checks if the point of the other corner is closer then 1 pixel away, because that should also be allowed. Can someone help me with this.
I already tried this code, but that just ignores it and still returns false:

```
public struct PointComparer : IEqualityComparer<(float x, float y)>
{
    public bool Equals((float x, float y) p1, (float x, float y) p2)
    {
        return Math.Abs(p1.x - p2.x) < 1f && Math.Abs(p1.y - p2.y) < 1f;
    }

    public int GetHashCode((float x, float y) obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

then I changed this line:

```
var isAdjacentTo = GetPoints().Intersect(other.GetPoints()).Count() >= 2;
```

to:

```
var isAdjacentTo = GetPoints().Intersect(other.GetPoints(), new PointComparer()).Count() >= 2;
```

But like I  already told u, that doesn't work...

Can someone tell me how to make this work?

Comment: how many hexagons are you expecting to have? is performance a concern?

Comment: No, maybe 12 hexagons

Comment: and do all hexagons has the same rotation degree and same size?

Comment: Yes they have. All equal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the hexagons all have the same rotation degree and same size you can simply the problem quite a lot.

The main idea is to calculate the distance between two hexagons' center. If the distance between their center point is `2x radius ± 1pixel` (or whatever epsilon you wish) then they "might" share one edge.

Now take the vector between the two center point and calculate the angle of the vector. If `(angle - 30) % 60 == 0` then they share one edge.

Special case: if two hexagons completely overlap then they will have the same center point

This way you only have to do two comparison with every other hexagons instead of 6x6 comparisons if you do the edge compare way.

Implementation should be quite trivial. The only tricky part would be to apply math formula to find the hexagon's center point. So I will leave it as exercise.

Edit:

Since its a hexagon grid, you got multiple ways of solving this. The center point way still applies. As long as the difference between the center points is less than `2x radius + 1pixel` they share one edge. Or you can calculate the distance between two line segments. If the distance between any edge a in hexagon A and any edge b in hexagon B is less than the radius then those two hexagon shares an edge.

Comment: No hexagon overlaps another, but `(angle - 30) % 60 == 0` includes the 1 pixel difference?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk 2x radius ± 1pixel includes the 1 pixel. Is it a hexagon grid? If so then you can further simply this.

Comment: Yes it tis a hexagon grid!

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help... Your way is so much easier!